# CNAME does not resolve, dig shows correct target, target does resolve

Tags: networking, dns, cname

I've setup a CNAME for `foo.example.com` (A) that points at `foo.bar.example.com` (B).

B resolves when accessed directly, and `nslookup` and `dig` show the correct nameservers. I can `ping` it.

A does not resolve, I can't `ping` it, `nslookup` fails, but `dig` returns

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;foo.example.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
foo.example.com.           176     IN      CNAME   foo.bar.example.com.
```

It seems like this should work, since `dig` is finding the correct target, which itself resolves, but nothing can hit successfully resolve `foo.example.com`

Comment: Perhaps `A` cannot resolve the `NS`'s for `bar.example.com.`

Comment: @Bib how can I check that?